# MacOS Recovery - Reinstall Monterary - upgraded to Ventura

Tags: macos, ventura, internet-recovery

I have an Apple Mac Mini M1 Silicon which I have kept updated (now Ventura).  However, I want to wipe it and reinstall MacOS.  However, when I go to Recovery its telling me I have "Reinstall Monterey".  I don't understand why when I upgraded to Ventura it didn't update the recovery partition.  I have connected the Mac to the internet but I can only get it to install Monterey - I can't find out how to do an internet recovery anywhere in the menus or on the internet.

I guess this means I need to reinstall Monterey, then upgrade to Ventura.  Which is a complete waste of time.

Is my Mac Mini faulty or how can I force it to update the recovery partition?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: I have the same issue on my Apple Silicon Mac. In my case I’d already upgraded to Sonoma but System Recovery is offering Monterey. I guess the upgrades to Ventura and later to Sonoma did not upgrade the recovery partition. You’re right that it’s a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

> Which is a complete waste of time.

The OS is on a secure, read-only volume. It will not boot if it has been modified in any way. It is the one part of your disk that is **guaranteed** to remain unchanged (for any given OS version). Wiping the disk and reinstalling the OS is therefore a complete waste of your time.

In Ventura's **System Settings**, you will find an option to **Erase all Content and Settings** (under **General** > **Transfer and Reset**), which will leave you with an 'as new' disk -- as if you had wiped it and reinstalled the OS, but without needing to do so.

Everything that you do on your disk is in a separate 'Data' volume from the OS. This separation means you just have to wipe the Data volume, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I think you have misunderstood me.  Im not going to modify anything.  My point was that:

I had a Mac with Monterey.  
I then updated to Ventura.  I expected MacOS to upgrade my recovery partition so if I had to do a Recovery it would show "Reinstall Ventura".   Instead, it shows "Reinstall Monterey", which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @hydev I understand, but I'm saying it doesn't matter because you don't need to wipe and reinstall the OS **ever**.

Comment: Ok -I see what you're saying. Thanks

Comment: @hydev A system update should also update the Recovery Partition. I'm not sure why that hasn't worked, but it may just sort itself out in a future OS update.